# How to debug an insert/update trigger to see values inserted/updated

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have this trigger that I'm trying to debug. I need to know the values that it's trying to insert. The below Print @Item is not working.

```
DECLARE @Item VARCHAR(MAX);



  INSERT INTO [BPRIL DATA ENTRY]
              ([COMPANY],
               [CUSTOMER],
               [ITEM #],
               [VENDOR],
               [SEASON],
               [BPRILP0CaseCost],
               [CustomerItem#])
  SELECT DISTINCT oh.company,
         oh.customer,
         @Item = ins.itemnumber,
         ins.vendor,
         oh.season,
         ins.VendorCost,
         oid.[CustomerSKU]
  FROM   [ORDER HEADER] AS oh
         LEFT JOIN [Order Item Detail] AS OID
           ON oh.[ORDER #] = OID.[ORDER #]
         LEFT JOIN [INSERTED] AS ins
           ON ins.[ITEM #] = OID.[ITEM #]
         LEFT JOIN [BPRIL DATA ENTRY] bp
           ON bp.[COMPANY] = oh.company
              AND bp.[CUSTOMER] = oh.customer
              AND bp.[ITEM #] = ins.itemnumber
              AND bp.[VENDOR] = ins.vendor
              AND bp.[SEASON] = oh.season
  WHERE  bp.[COMPANY] IS NULL
         AND bp.[CUSTOMER] IS NULL
         AND bp.[ITEM #] IS NULL
         AND bp.[VENDOR] IS NULL
         AND bp.[SEASON] IS NULL
         AND (OID.[STATUS] = 'C'
         OR OID.[STATUS] = 'I')
         AND ins.[VENDOR] IS NOT NULL
         AND ins.[QUOTE #] IS NOT NULL
         AND ins.[VENDORCOST] IS NOT NULL 

Print @Item;
```

Comment: Can you not select it out of the table [BPRIL DATA ENTRY]?  And why a @Item variable?  ins.itemnumber would be in the table [BPRIL DATA ENTRY]

Comment: @Item was the variable that I wanted to see so that's why I created that variable... for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE DebugTrace
(
   [COMPANY] NVARCHAR(2),
   [CUSTOMER] NVARCHAR(255),
   [ITEM #] NVARCHAR(35),
   [VENDOR] NVARCHAR(50),
   [SEASON] INT,
   [BPRILP0CaseCost] MONEY,
   [CustomerItem#] NVARCHAR(50)
)
```

Then I ran the Trigger to Insert into DebugTrace instead of [BPRIL DATA ENTRY]

Answer (score 10):

@cadrell0 is correct, you should not set something to a variable in an insert statement. Nor should you ever be setting anything to a scalar variable in a trigger. Inserted and deleted tables may have more than one row and thus more than one value. You need to think in terms of **sets** for triggers.

However, here is my process for developing a trigger and seeing what is going on.

First, I figure out the code outside of the trigger (On dev this may mean dropping the existing trigger while you work things out for a major change).

So I set up and populate the inserted and or deleted tables as temp tables in a script (Iscript out the actual table and change the name to make this easier). I make sure to populate them with multiple records (very important!) and with data that will satisfy my test cases.

Then I write the code (minus the create trigger part) and use the #inserted and/or #deleted temp tables anywhere that I  would use inserted or deleted. Now I can run one part at a time and see my results  along the way if need be. I can also put everything in a transaction and roll it back at the end so that I can continue to use the same test data repeatedly until I get it right.

Once I know my code does what I want it to do, I remove the transactions, the temp table code and any test code and globally replace the # sign with nothing (so the trigger-only tables are now called inserted and/or deleted). Then I add in the create trigger code and create the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a variable and insert into a table at the same time.  You will need to do this in two separate queries.